# Are there scales to measure parental autonomy support from the parents' perspective? (Self-determination theory)

Tags: measurement, motivation, parenting

Self-determination theory posits that parental autonomy support (PAS) has myriad benefits for children. All the studies I have been able to find either rate PAS based on observing parents interact with their children and coding the observations, or administer scales to the children to assess their perceptions of PAS. Do you know of any scales that directly ask parents about their behaviors in order to measure autonomy support?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  This is an interesting question and I haven't had a chance to fully review it yet, but I wondered if you had a look through https://selfdeterminationtheory.org/research/development-and-parenting/ ? Where have you looked so far?

Comment: @ChrisRogers Thank you! I have looked through all the scales here https://selfdeterminationtheory.org/questionnaires/ , done some google scholar searches, and searched the references in some papers that seemed related to the topic. Unfortunately I did not keep track of all these searches and the blind alleys I found... I think the closest scale to what I need is the P-PASS (Mageau et al., 2015, 10.1037/a0039325), but adapted so that it asks the parents about their own behavior rather than asking the children.